# How can debug messages in erb be supressed in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, erb

I want to print out some debug messages in my erb template when it is called in development mode, but not when it is called in production mode (i.e.)

```
<%= debug variable_name %>
```

However, this will be printed in any mode.

I found I can do

```
<% if logger.debug?
     debug variable_name
   end %>
```

which seems to work. Is this the proper way, or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
<%= debug(variable) if RAILS_ENV == 'development' %>
```

If you're doing this often, you might want to create a quick helper method to clean up the code a little more:

```
def my_debug(debug_variable)
debug_variable if RAILS_ENV == 'development'
end
```

Then you can do this in your erb template/view

```
my_debug(variable_here)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll look around for a better way but for now that could be a one liner:

```
<%= debug(variable) if logger.debug? %>
```

**Edit:** If you're going to have this type of code everywhere maybe a helper would do the trick.

```
def fancy_debuggin(f)
  debug(f) if logger.debug?
end

<%= fancy_debuggin(variable) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the logger.debug? function to test if logging is switched on you can place a direct call to logger.debug.

There is a performance hit, usually pretty marginal, with this approach as you have to evaluate the string passed to the logger.debug method even if the logger is not at debug level. This is only a problem where you have a relatively expensive string.

So your code would look something like this

```
<%= logger.debug(variable) %>
```

Comment: Well that depends. When the log level is set to debug it does. When it's set to a higher level e.g. info or warn then no it doesn't.